# Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8'

Tags: json, flutter, file, decode

When I try to read a JSON file from local directory facing error *`Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8'`*

I assume that this is due to the fact that the JSON file is vety big (`4mb`). When file size is `330k`b there is no error.
How to read jsondata from a big txt file in dart

```
final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final File file = File('${directory.path}/$test_json.txt');
final response = await file.readAsString(encoding: utf8);
```

Comment: That means the data is *not* UTF8. What's the actual error? Most likely it tells you what the invalid bytes were and where they appeared.

Comment: UTF8 isn't some kind of escape sequence. This page is UTF8, like most web sites. In the range 0x00-0x7F it's *identical* to single-byte codepages, so if the text you got was encoded as eg Latin1 but contained only English letters, there would be no difference. Characters above that are encoded using 2 or more bytes. If the larger files contained such characters but were saved as eg Latin1, UTF8 decoding would faile

Comment: You can try the [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) module to detect the actual encoding of the failing file. The code that produced it should be fixed to actually save it as UTF8